# FFTW3 compute cross-correlation in the same signal

Tags: c++, c, signal-processing, fft, correlation

I am currently creating a C code, which takes as an input a `wav` file (specifically just one channel of the original `wav` file), and it performs the short-time Fourier transform.
The main part of the code is this one:

```
stft_data = (fftw_complex*)(fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*windowSize));

fft_result= (fftw_complex*)(fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*windowSize));

storage = (fftw_complex*)(fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*storage_capacity));

//define the fftw plane
fftw_plan plan_forward;
plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(windowSize, stft_data, fft_result, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

//integer indexes
int i,counter ;
counter = 0 ;
//create a Hamming window
double hamming_result[windowSize];
hamming(windowSize, hamming_result);

//implement the stft position indexes
int chunkPosition = 0; //actual chunk position
int readIndex ; //read the index of the wav file

while (chunkPosition < wav_length ){
    //read the window
    for(i=0; i<windowSize; i++){

      readIndex = chunkPosition + i;

      if (readIndex < wav_length){
        stft_data[i] = wav_data[readIndex]*hamming_result[i]*_Complex_I  + 0.0*I;
      }
      else{
        //if we are beyond the wav_length
        stft_data[i] = 0.0*_Complex_I + 0.0*I;//padding
        break;
      }
    }
    //compute the fft
    fftw_execute(plan_forward);
    //store the stft in a data structure
    for (i=0; i<windowSize;i++)
    {
      //printf("RE: %.2f  IM: %.2f\n", creal(fft_result[i]),cimag(fft_result[i]));
      storage[counter] = creal(fft_result[i]) + cimag(fft_result[i]);
      counter+=1;
    }

    //update indexes
    chunkPosition += hop_size;
    printf("Chunk Position %d\n", chunkPosition);
    printf("Counter position %d\n", counter);
    printf("Fourier transform done\n");

}
```

Once the FFT has been computed onto the selected window, I am storing the FFT real and imaginary part into a `storage` variable.

After that I would like to compute the cross correlation among the data points in each of the N windows I have in the end. 
As an example, I would like to compute the correlation between the  first data point of the first window ( `storage[0]` ) with the first element of the second window (`storage[windowSize+1]`).
However, I am facing some problems and I don't have reasonable values. According to what I studied, the correlation in the Fourier space it is just the complex multiplication between two Fourier terms. Thus,
what I am doing is something like :

```
correlation = storage[0]*conj(storage[windowSize+1]);
```

However, I got very huge values, which makes me wonder if I am really computing a correlation.

Where am I wrong? 
How should I scale my correlation results? 
How should I compute the correlation with the Fourier values?
and then, how should I plot the Fourier values I have from FFTW3 calculations? should I shift all the values or are they already shifted?

Thanks very much

Comment: `storage[windowSize+1] ` is the second element of the next window

Comment: Hi @doug you're right. However, this is just an example of a possible cross-correlation I would like to compute, namely  between the first element of the first window and the second one of the next window

Comment: Could it be that you are looking for [normalized cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Zero-normalized_cross-correlation_(ZNCC)) ? This is generally closer to what I would expect in physics, a value in `[-1, 1]` instead of arbitrarily large. I'm not versed in any way in signal processing, though, so I simply don't know what the unnormalized correlation is good for.

Comment: Oh, also, shouldn't it be the SUM of multiplication between fourier terms? Something like `cor[n] = SUM( storage[m] * conj(storage(windowSize+m+n)))` ?

Comment: Hi @GeckoGeorge , 
normalized cross-correlation is exactly what I want. I did not try as you said, summing up all the contributions, I am going to see

Answer (score 1):

The line `storage[counter] = creal(fft_result[i]) + cimag(fft_result[i]);` makes storage purely real. Since computing `correlation = storage[0]*conj(storage[windowSize+1]);` is the next step in the computation of the cross correlation, there is a problem. Indeed, there is no point in conjugating a real number.

Trying `storage[counter] = fft_result[i];` could partly resolve the issue.
In addition, `correlation = storage[0]*conj(storage[windowSize+1]);` should be modified to `correlation = storage[0]*conj(storage[windowSize]);`

By performing `correlation = storage[0]*conj(storage[windowSize]);`, the magnitude of index [0] of the DFT of the correlation is obtained. Indeed, `storage[0]` corresponds to the average of the first frame, while `storage[windowSize]` corresponds to the average of the second frame. It is not equal to the averages, but much larger, as it is scaled by the length of the frame `windowSize`.

To compute the correlation between the two signals, the next step should be:

```
for (i=0; i<windowSize;i++)
{
    dftofcorrelation[i]=storage[i]*conj(storage[i+windowSize]
}
```

Then, the inverse DFT must be applied to the array `dftofcorrelation` to get the correlation as an array. It must be kept in mind that neither the forward nor the backward DFT of FFTW include any scaling, see [what FFTW really computes](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html#The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029):

```
fftw_execute(plan_backward);
```

If two scalars are to be retained of this correlation array, it's its maximum (high if the signal are similar up to a delay) and the index of the maximum, that is the estimated time offset between the two signals.

The overall scaling induced by FFTW is a power of `windowSize` (windowSize^3?). It can be checked by computing the autocorrelation of a uniform signal (which is uniform).